# issues with horizontal scrolling using jQuery.ScrollTo / jQuery.SerialScroll

Tags: jquery, scrollto, horizontal-scrolling, serialscroll

I am trying to develop auto horizontal scrolling for our website using - jQuery.ScrollTo / jQuery.SerialScroll. I am not sure if this is the best jquery library to do that, but if there's something better, please let me know.

Here's the behavior that I want, check out [foursquare's](http://foursquare.com/) "Recent Activity" list. The data that will refresh will come from a ajax request that I make every few seconds using window.setInterval. I am not really a CSS/java script guy so I havent been able to figure out jQuery.SerialScroll.

Here's the [website](http://hiretwits.com) - look at the "Live job Feeds" list. Currently the list does refresh the data coming from the ajax call, but I dont see the effect, the animation, in fact I dont even think serialScroll is being used. Right now I am doing a - $('#feed-ticker').prepend(content) to pre-append the newly arrived data.

You can do a view source to look at the current code.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.scrollTo()` (and by extension, the SerialScroll plugin) adjusts the position of the **browser's scrollbar**.  For example, `$(document).scrollTo()` is great for smoothly scrolling to a different spot on your document.  (You can, of course, also adjust the scroll position of a block element with the style `overflow:auto` or `overflow:scroll`.)

Eyeballing the site you linked to, it looks like they're not using `scrollTo()` to achieve the animated new item behavior.  Rather, the containing block's style is set to `overflow:hidden` and the new items are created with a `height` of zero.  Once inserted in to the page, the new item's height is then animated to 75px (or whatever).  This might be a better approach for you to take.

Assuming `content` is a jQuery object:

```
content.height(0);
$('#feed-ticker').prepend(content);
content.animate({
    height: 75 // or whatever your target height is
}, 500); // animation's duration in milliseconds
```

Magic!

Comment: thanks for your response, but the problem with this solution is that the height is not fixed, it varies based on contents in the breadcrumbs div tag.

Comment: okay!! i got it, used hide instead of height. so basically did this...

$feed.hide();
$feed.slideDown();

Thank you very much.